# How to write a backslash character in makefile for pythonanywhere

Tags: makefile, backslash

I need to concatenate a String in makefile to get this output:

```
username\$databasename
```

for automating the build process for a django project.

I've figured out that the $ sign has to be $$ in makefile so this is what i have now:

```
MYVAR = username$$databasename
```

My problem is the backslash in the string! As I know, the `\\` like usually the backslash is escaped does not work here because it is meant for the linebreak function of Makefiles.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll probably want to try `myvar = username\\"$$"databasename`.

With

```
rule : 
  @echo $(myvar)
```

This outputs `username\$databasename`.

If you think the double quotes are ugly, single quotes work just as fine: `myvar = username\\'$$'databasename`.

---

If `databasename` is stored in an environment variable you want to access then use:

`myvar = username\\$$"$$databasename"`

for example, `myvar = username\\$$"$$USER"` would output `username\$guiltydolphin` for me.

Answer (score 0):

In a Makefile I sometimes want to include scripts or fragments of python
code in a say Latex document.

I define BACKSLASH as Makefile macro and then use it in echo statements.

```
BACKSLASH = '\\'

reactance_sim: reactance.py
        echo "{"$(BACKSLASH)tiny           >  reactance_sim
        echo $(BACKSLASH)"begin{verbatim}" >> reactance_sim
        cat reactance.py                   >> reactance_sim
        echo $(BACKSLASH)"end{verbatim}"   >> reactance_sim
        echo "}"                           >> reactance_sim
        cp reactance_sim reactance_simulation.tex
        # vi reactance_simulation.tex
```

The above Makefile code will take the reactance.py file and
if required create a reactance_sim file which will have 
backslashes in it (in this case Latex commands like \tiny and \begin)